# How to read audit4j records

Tags: java, audit4j

I am trying to find examples where we read audit events from for audit4j.

So far I have used JDBC calls to read data from database tables. The problem is that elements column of that table stores serialized objects as varchar string.

When reading from ObjectOutputStream, I am getting StreamCurroptedException.

So I guess I am looking for ways to read audited events with all related data. So far I have not found any good way to do that. Can somebody please point me in the right direction.

Comment: This seems as an important question, I'm surprised nobody can answer it?! There isn't much point storing the data in the DB if you can't easily query it.

Comment: any news about this?